# Can not use @johmun/vue-tags-input with VueJS and Laravel/Spark

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-spark

I currently set up a new playground with VueJS/Laravel/Spark and want to implement a tags input component.

I don't understand how to register those components correctly. I'm following the how-to-guides and official documentation, but the implementation just works so-so.

I want to implement the library from @johmun -> http://www.vue-tags-input.com which I installed via npm (`npm install @johmun/vue-tags-input`).

I created a single file component named `VueTagsInput.vue`  that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-tags-input
      v-model="tag"
      :tags="tags"
      @tags-changed="newTags => tags = newTags"
      :autocomplete-items="filteredItems"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueTagsInput from '@johmun/vue-tags-input';

export default {
  components: {
    VueTagsInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tag: '',
      tags: [],
      autocompleteItems: [{
        text: 'Spain',
      }, {
        text: 'France',
      }, {
        text: 'USA',
      }, {
        text: 'Germany',
      }, {
        text: 'China',
      }],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.autocompleteItems.filter(i => {
        return i.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.tag.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I imported this single file component at `resources/js/bootstrap.js` like so:

```
import VueTagsInput from './VueTagsInput.vue'
```

And I'm using this component in the `home.blade.php` view like this:

```
<vue-tags-input v-model="tag" 
                autocomplete-always-open 
                add-from-paste 
                allow-edit-tags>
</vue-tags-input>
```

This renders an input with which I can interact as desired, but I can not use the autocomplete function with the countries entered above, and the console also throws the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "tag" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use `<vue-tags-input />` in your `home.blade.php` and add `autocomplete-always-open add-from-paste allow-edit-tags` to the "original" `vue-tags-input` inside your component

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled across the solution by trial & error.

First I had to register the component the right way in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` like so:

```
import VueTagsInput from './VueTagsInput.vue'
Vue.component('vue-tags-input', VueTagsInput);
```

But this caused another error because I called the component within the component registration itself. I used the name option in the single file component in order to overcome this error. I gave my newly created component a different name like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <johmun-vue-tags-input
      v-model="tag"
      :tags="tags"
      @tags-changed="newTags => tags = newTags"
      :autocomplete-items="filteredItems"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import JohmunVueTagsInput from '@johmun/vue-tags-input';

export default {
  name: "VueTagsInput",
  components: {
    JohmunVueTagsInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tag: '',
      tags: [],
      autocompleteItems: [{
        text: 'Spain',
      }, {
        text: 'France',
      }, {
        text: 'USA',
      }, {
        text: 'Germany',
      }, {
        text: 'China',
      }],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.autocompleteItems.filter(i => {
        return i.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.tag.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```